# Изображения в google фотографии

Tags: google-photo

Может кто знает как получить прямую ссылку на изображение в google фотографии? А то сейчас ссылку скопируешь, а на следующий день она уже другая на это изображение.

Comment: А при чем здесь программирование и этот сайт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути Google Photo, это практически то же самое, что Picasa и Google+.

Можете использовать программу [Image Uploader](http://zenden.ws/ru/imageuploader), она позволяет получать прямые ссылки вида

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gib2QbxwWGE/VfEqFJeIb_I/AAAAAAAAGIg/IfiFvFKPNKE/s0/screenshot%2525202015-09-10%252520002.png
```

Выберите в ней сервер Picasa WebAlbums.

Comment: тот что нужно, но как вы это сделали там же нет загрузки на Google Photo или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: все понял, большое спасибо